# How to find all published Pharmacophore Structure of a Drug target?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, drugs, medicinal-chemistry

Other than literature review how do you find the structures of Pharmacophore of a drug target? I am searching Pyruvate Dehydrogenase Kinase (PDK) inhibitors and I have reviewed lots of literature but I've only found few structures. I have tried searching google by "PDK inhibitors patent reviews" "PDK inhibitors general review" but I am not finding any concrete literature. There are 4 sub classes: PDK1, PDK2, PDK3 and PDK4.

I am looking for drug candidates which are potential Pharmacophore for this drug class.